# sql database - each row in a table with extra data in different tables

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, relationship

I have a table let's call it MainTable, each row of this table have several common fields, but depending on the value of let's say field1 then the row can have one field or another, for example, if field1 is 1 then the row most storage a field2 and field3 and if field1 is 2 then the row most storage a field4 and field5, and field2/field3 are different from field4/field5 even in type, please some help, i need a solution to design the database with this conditions, i don't know if put all the field in MainTable or create different table for the extra data, the values posibles for field1 are 30.

Comment: Could you possibly include an example of the data? I am having trouble visualizing your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn about **[Database_normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)**

What you are asking is include information for some rows instead of every row, so you will have lot of columns with nulls with current design.

What you do is create aditional tables and link using a foreign key.

Imagine you have a table `Cars`  with fields

```
car_id, color, size, num_wheels
```

But some cars are recreational vehicule and have aditional properties. So instead of add aditional columns in your `Cars` table you create another table `RV_cars`

```
car_id, bathroom_size, num_bed, bol_tv
```

So if you want get all information of one rv car you do

```
SELECT C.*, R.*
FROM Cars  C
join RV_cars R
  ON C.car_id = R.car_id
```

Comment: ok I get that, that is why Im asking, to see what is better, the null fields or the extra tables, the car_id of each table is the same? and if that is the solution then I need to have 30 extra tables like RV_cars, is that ok? Even for future consultations or reports about all the cars.

Comment: the question about car_id field what I mean is if car_id is primary key of the second table too or just a foreign key, thanks for your help.

Comment: For this case `RV_car` can be both `PK` and `FK` But is best practice have a different PK like `RV_car_id` in case you use it on other table later. And yes for you case you create additiional tables to store the related information. For example you can have another table for `Tires` with `tire_id, width, radio, material` and just save `tire_id` in your `cars` table

Comment: but then again I have a table_id for each extra table in my table cars, depending on the info some of this fields will be null.

Comment: not sure what are you asking now because I dont know your schema. I answer the question and provide the documentation you need. try to play a litle with it, and If you need help with other issues you can prepare another more detailed question. You can use a fiddle to share your schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd34b8/2

Comment: what I mean is if I have Cars table and BrazilCars table with fields only for cars from Brazil and EcuadorCars table with fields only for cars from Ecuador and I put in Cars table both FK of each two extra tables then if the car is from brazil the column for ecuador FK will be null.

Comment: That is correct. Or you dont put the FK in cars. And perform a `LEFT JOIN` between cars and brazilCars both are valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use noSQL data storage. If i understand u - u would have about 15 different pairs of fields, so relational database isnt for u. Or u need to create 16 tables (1 Main and 15 with `extra` data) and hold key in main table